# running an asp.net core 2.0 app remotely executed in a server by using dotnet CLI

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm newbie deploying asp.net core apps. I developed an asp.net core 2.0 web app and is hosted in a server folder. For debugging reasons, I executed app directly by using dotnet command because I need to check some logger information, app started listening in http://localhost:5000, however I have to execute it remotely and in my client PC providing http://serverIp:5000/ shows an error. ¿How can I do to make work?

Comment: make sure that pc can connect to port 5000 on the network stack you are using with tools or cmd line checks like telnet

Comment: No sucess!, can't open connection to host, port 5000: Connection error. I shutdown client and server firewall to check and no changes, same error.

Comment: no success with your app, or no success with network tools proving the network and port is not working?

Comment: No success trying telnet to ip and port.

Comment: then you have a network issue, not a code issue.